# Xamarin Using iOS & Android Third Party Library

Tags: xamarin

I am considering Xamarin. I come from C# background, and experienced in building native iOS & Android apps.

Most of the apps I build make heavy use of 3rd party libraries which are available for iOS & Android. In Xamarin it appears you have to go through a "binding" process in order to use iOS or Android libs.

Is this problematic in Xamarin?

What issues or limitations should I anticipate?

Comment: Not going to post as an answer, since I'm not incredibly familiar with Xamarin, but I believe the appeal is a single app should work in multiple environments with minimal modifications. Using iOS or Android specific dependencies will naturally require more device specific maintenance.

Comment: The complexity of binding a native library is going to depend highly on the design of the library and your familiarity with it.  An API with a single class and 5 public methods will obviously easier to bind than one with 500 methods spread over 50 different classes.

Comment: @Jason - thanks, that makes sense. How about adding things like Ad Network libraries and such are there any hidden caveats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin has a components team designed to create/maintain quality bindings for some of the most popular 3rd party libraries. You can see majority of their work here:

https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents

**Note:** These are only the open-source components. There are many bindings built by various team members on personal githubs in addition.

There is also a complete component store that you can search for popular third party libraries that work in `Xamarin`:

https://components.xamarin.com/

Otherwise you can search NuGet for `Xamarin` compatible packages. Sadly there isn't a great filter to do this in NuGet that I'm aware of.

https://www.nuget.org/

If there are libraries that are not bound by the components team, typically the community has already created either A) Xamarin C# port, or B) Binding project. There is a popular `awesome-xamarin` repository that has links to many of these libraries:

https://github.com/benoitjadinon/awesome-xamarin

In the worst case, Xamarin provides binding tooling to do 90%+ of the work for you.

Android - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/

iOS - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/

If you get to this case, there are caveats such as having to know Java/Objective-C and how the language should convert to the respective C# equivalents.

For example, here is a `Xamarin.Android` binding guide in the case that you were to run into further issues:

https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

**Note:** The official Xamarin documentation includes troubleshooting for just about every issue you can think of. If there's something that's not documented or confusing, you can always open up a Stack Overflow or Xamarin Forums question on the topic!

Comment: Thanks, this helps.